# Trouble understanding an x86-64 function preamble

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I am experiencing a crash, and while investigating I found myself totally blocked by the following code:

```
0000000000000a00 <_IO_vfprintf>:
a00:       55                      push   %rbp
a01:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
a04:       41 57                   push   %r15
a06:       41 56                   push   %r14
a08:       41 55                   push   %r13
a0a:       41 54                   push   %r12
a0c:       53                      push   %rbx
a0d:       48 81 ec 48 06 00 00    sub    $0x648,%rsp
a14:       48 89 95 98 f9 ff ff    mov    %rdx,0xfffffffffffff998(%rbp)
```

This is generated by running `objdump --disassemble /usr/lib64/libc.a` on a 64-bit Linux x86 system, and then searching through the output. This is [AT&T syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax), so destinations are on the right.

Specifically, I don't understand the last instruction. It seems to be writing the value of the `rdx` register into memory somewhere on the stack (far, far away), before the function has touched that register. To me, this doesn't make any sense.

I tried reading up on the calling conventions, and my best theory now is that `rdx` is used for a parameter, so the code is basically "returning" the parameter value directly. This is not the end of the function, so it's not really returning, of course.

Comment: Maybe Raymond could help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/14/58579.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's a parameter.  The [ABI used by Linux](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) assigns up to 6 "INTEGER" (<= 64-bit integer, or pointer) type parameters to registers, in the obvious and easy-to-remember order `%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, `%rcx`, `%r8`, `%r9`.

The stack frame is 1648 bytes (`sub $0x648,%rsp` claims 1608 bytes, plus 5 64-bit registers have been pushed before that), and `0xfffffffffffff998` is -1640.

So the code is storing the 3rd parameter near the bottom of the stack frame.

(Note: the Windows 64-bit ABI is different to the Linux one.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I really should take some time (5-10 years or so) and get back into the groove with assembly programming.

Comment: If sure would have been nice to render `0xfffffffffffff998` as `-1640` by default. That would be much more easy to understand and wouldn't be dependant on 64 bit address space.